# Cannot empty a TextInput while in focus

Tags: react-native

I have the following issue with a TextInput

- User types: `Hello`
- Input field shows `Hello`
- I clear the text input without losing focus
- Input field shows `""`
- User types: `A`
- Input field shows `HelloA`

If the user removes the focus from the `TextInput` and focuses back on it before typing again, the behavior goes as expected and the new text contains only the input from after the clearing

How can I properly clear the `TextInput` without the need to go off focus?

Here is the minimum code required to trigger the issue:

```
export default class MyInput extends Component {
  clearInput() {
    this.textInput.clear();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="clear" onPress={this.clearInput.bind(this)} />
        <TextInput
          ref={component => (this.textInput = component)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: <TextInput
          ref={component => (this.textInput = component)}
          multiline={true}
          onContentSizeChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.userInput}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          autoFocus={true}
clearTextOnFocus
        />

try this

Comment: The code you've been describing should work. `setState` should work even with an empty string. Can you paste the full code ? On codepaste or similar.

Comment: @whitep4nther I added a simple code that reproduces the issue. I noticed that this issue doesn't happen if the TextInput is not multiline (but I need it to be multiline)

Comment: @BhavanPatel This solution works but only if I lose focus and get focus again. It's a progress, but is there a way to clear the text while still in focus?

Comment: I reformulated the whole question to be more focused

Comment: @whitep4nther nevermind... it happens even when it's not multiline...

Comment: Your minimal code example works on my computer. Which version of RN are you using ? Are you running the code on iOS or Android?

Comment: Running the code on Android with react 0.44.2. It works even when you don't put the TextInput out of focus?

Comment: Upgraded to react 0.5 and I have the same issue